# Botones que no funcionan en android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

tengo 2 botones y no funcionan, no se por que, los ids estan bien declarados tanto en la vista de xml como en el codigo del fragmento.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#305EFA"
    android:text="Log in"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/error_field" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/changeToRegister"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textColor="#305EFA"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:strokeColor="#305EFA"
    app:strokeWidth="3dp" />
```

These are the buttons.

```
    binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener {
        val email = binding.emailField.text.toString()
        val password = binding.loginPasswordField.text.toString()
        if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener{
                if (it.isSuccessful){
                    binding.emailField.setText("")
                    binding.loginPasswordField.setText("")
                    showToast("Has iniciado correctamente")
                    showHome(it.result.user!!.email!!, password)
                }else{
                    binding.errorField.text = "La contraseña es incorrecta o el usuario no existe"
                }
            }
        }else{
            showToast("Introduce el correo y la contraseña correctamente")
        }
    }

private fun showRegister(){
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_registerFragment_to_loginFragment)
}
```

}

Cuando clicko cualquiera de los 2 botones, simplemente no hace nada. y no tiene sentido. Las cosas estan bien escritas.

p<ÑOASDbÑ:saiASIkdgÑvAWIucat Gvadsf<ñivhafsdutgñlcañcgsvafSDIÑañfisvdasiñIÑGVHFÑIHVAsafiñvfwaviyDSAFIHAsfvihASFvihafsvhifasñihAsihfVasvih`9ÉSFefgâvadsv¨gsvgdaysfyavgs^yfgd>s^(yfS^y(fgapf(geacpts

Comment: Bienvenido. Para preguntas en inglés ve a [so].

Comment: Hay algún mensaje de error registrado en el LogCat?